# Set Variable in ClassA and View in ClassB

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new/learning Objective-C and iOS dev - have a basic question here I can't get my head around.

I have 2 classes.

In ClassA, in the header file I have defined a NSString object (`planetNameImage`) so it is publicly accessible. Then in the .m file i set it using:

```
self.planetNameImage = planetSelected;
```

In ClassB, I'm trying to retrieve this value so I first instanitate ClassA, using:

```
ClassA *claA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
```

Then try to call that variable using:

```
NSString *imageName = claA.planetNameImage;
```

However this isn't working - any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't working as in...? Getting the wrong value? Compilation errors? ...?

Comment: Post your complete code (including the declaration). It's hard to figure out what's going on from 3 disjoint fragments.

Comment: you'd better post more details :)

Comment: You cannot create a new instance of ClassA and expect it to have te same ivar values as the other one. You are missing the point f object oriented programming

Comment: Where exactly in your .m file are you doing the below?
Then in the .m file i set it using:
self.planetNameImage = planetSelected;

Comment: In the prepareForSegue method (using storyboards).

Comment: @Rob van der Veer - Yes i see your point. How do I refer the the existing object then?

Comment: @SaeUs, to access your ClassA instance in classB, you need to pass  `self` to the classB object when you create it. For explanation, see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html

Comment: @Rob van der Veer - So in ClassA, would i simply say self whatever variable equals a NSString object in Class B?

Comment: Eerrm,no.  Add a property `ClassA *thing;` to class b, after you create class b, set `newB.thing = self;` then youcan use the classA instance by referencing `self.thing` in the methods of class b. i hope you understand, its basic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

What about?

```
ClassA.h

@interface ClassA:NSObject
   @property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *planetNameImage
@end

ClassB.m
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassB
- (void)someFunc
  {
      ClassA *instance = [ClassA new];
      instance.planetNameImage = @"name of image";
      NSString *imageName = instance.planetNameImage;
  }
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

To access instance variable of a class into other class you need to define it as property.
you can do that as below

in classA.h

```
@property (nonatomic,copy)   NSString * planetNameImage;
```

in ClassA.m

```
@synthesize planetNameImage;
```

`@property` will  create setter & getter method for planetNameImage and you can use it in classB.

Comment: Hi,
I've created that property (with the synthensize in the m file as i'm using iOS6) still not coming through on the ClassB side.

Comment: please write me how you are accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Best Way is pass `NSString` name is  `planetNameImage` to your **ClassB**.

write code when you switch to Class B.

```
ClassB *obj = [[ClassB alloc] init];
obj.newString = planetNameImage; 
[obj presentModelViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Dont forget to put `NSString *newString` and also set `@property` too, At ClassB.h file.

Comment: Why presentViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `planetNameImage` as its property

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *planetNameImage ;
```

and in .m file

```
synthesize planetNameImage ;
```

Also , I think you need to put the following statement in the `init` method of `ClassA`

```
self.planetNameImage = planetSelected;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to deal with this.

**Method I**: *Declare iVar and expose accessor method*

```
// .h file
@interface ClassA : NSObject {
    NSString    *planetNameImage;
}

- (NSString*) getPlanetNameImage;

@end

// .m file
@implementation ClassA

- (NSString*) getPlanetNameImage {
    return planetNameImage;
}

@end
```

**Method I**: *Declare property and synthesize*

```
// .h file
@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString    *planetNameImage;

@end

// .m file
@implementation ClassA

@synthesize planetNameImage;

@end
```

How to use in ClassB

```
#import "ClassA.h" 

- (void) someClassBMethod {
     ClassA *claA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
     NSLog(@"String: %@", [claA getPlanetNameImage]);
     //OR
     NSLog(@"String: %@", claA.planetNameImage);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

ClassA.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *planetNameImage;
```

ClassA.m

```
@synthesize planetNameImage = _planetNameImage;

_planetNameImage = planetSelected;
```

ClassB.m

```
NSString *imageName = classA.planetNameImage;
```